# Date Time ins LIST

Tags: date-time

I Have a list (Orders list) where i have a column "CreationDate" as internal name.

That column stores datetime of the order.

When I show this column in a View, it appears in the format "dd/mm/yyyy" and  that is good for me.

The problem comes when I need to do it:

```
myItens = (from SPListItem item in list.Items
                           where (Convert.ToDateTime(item["DateCreation"]).ToShortDateString() == Convert.ToDateTime("12/14/2012").ToShortDateString() ) && // Convert.ToDateTime("14/12/2012").ToShortDateString()) &&
                                   (item["Statut"].ToString() == "En cours de traitement") &&
                                   (item["TypeLigne"].ToString() == tLigne)
                           select item).ToList();
```

... for the Convert.ToDateTime("12/14/2012").ToShortDateString() it answer me for this format: "12/14/2012"... if i use the correct (14/12/2012) format it doesnt work!!

I receive a error message like the date is not in correct format.

Someone can help?

Thnk you.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the Convert.ToDateTime method description on the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz1w05e%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

> If value is not null, the return value is the result of invoking the
>   DateTime.Parse method on value using the formatting information in a
>   DateTimeFormatInfo object that is initialized for the current culture

You said "if I use the correct 14/12/2012": if your server locale is English, then it's not the correct format, and that's why 12/14/2012 is parsed correctly.
If you need to parse a date with a specific format, you should use the `DateTime.ParseExact(value, format, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)` method.